# Center Fabricjs iText produces a blurry effect

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to add an IText element to the center of the canvas, but when I call the `canvas.centerObject(object)` method, the text gets blurred.

You have an example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JaviGL/dc3k1r5o/).

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',{
  width:400,
  height:400
});
canvas.setBackgroundColor('#f4f2f2', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

$('#add-text-btn').click(function() {
  var text = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
    fill: '#333',
    fontSize: 14,
  });
  canvas.add(text);
})

$('#add-ugly-text-btn').click(function() {
  var text = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
    fill: '#333',
    fontSize: 14,
  });
  canvas.add(text);
  //canvas.centerObject(text);
  text.center();
  text.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-text-btn">Add text</button>
<button id="add-ugly-text-btn">Add centered text</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you create an issue in [github](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/new) and link this question there.

Comment: @Durga Adding controls to increase the size of the text, I discovered that the same thing happened and the text lost clarity. So before creating a new issue as you suggested me, I've been doing some research on github and I found an issue that seemed to be related to my problem: [link](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/279).

Following the instructions I found there, I decided to set objectCaching to false and I think I managed to solve the problem.

Thank you for the suggestion!